# I see a DLL in GAC_MSIL but there's not an assembly

Tags: php, .net, vb.net, com, com-interop

I'm looking at my ClassLibrary1.dll inside

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ClassLibrary1\v4.0_1.0.0.0__2efc1c0b243a0c09
```

that was placed there automatically as a result of this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil.
exe /i "C:\Users\wherever\ClassLibrary1.dll"
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>
```

But afterward a corresponding assembly is nowhere to be found inside

```
C:\Windows\assembly
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'd like to be able to use that class library with the following code:

```
<?php
 $obj = new DOTNET("ClassLibrary1", "Version=1.0.0.0", "Culture=neutral", "PublicKeyToken=2efc1c0b243a0c09", "ClassLibrary1.Class1"); 
 $output=$obj->HelloWorld();
 echo $output;
?>
```

The class looks like this:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub HelloWorld()
        MsgBox("hello, world")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is your Class's Namespace and Root Namespace of the project?

Answer (score 3):

I assume it's a .net 4 assembly?  If so, notice how none of the .net 4 assemblies are listed in \Windows\assembly.

That's because .net 4 assemblies are in a different location.  This is nothing to worry about, so long as you can use the assembly in the GAC.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.  Yes, it's a .net 4 assembly.  At least an attempted one, because the only thing I see so far is that ClassLibrary1.dll file in the GAC_MSIL folder (as "ClassLibrary1.dll").  It doesn't have the same icon as the stuff I see in \Windows\assembly (but yet none of them do, do they, so I guess that at least is a good sign).  I still can't get the class to express through PHP.  Don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Basically I don't yet know if I can use the assembly in the GAC; is everything in the proper place thus far as you can tell from what I've described?

Comment: Did you properly sign the assembly?  GAC requires a valid signature.

Comment: Thank's also for calling my attention to this:  "If so, notice how none of the .net 4 assemblies are listed in \Windows\assembly."

Comment: Even though my project is in VB.NET, I went to Solution Explorer!Properties in VS2010 and clicked the Signing tab on the left. Then checked the "Sign the assembly" box, and selected a strong name key file into that field. I built the dll, then used gacutil.exe on it and got command line feedback that the assembly had been successfully added to the cache. So hopefully more or less the same happened with that as if I'd written the project using MSVC, but maybe that isn't the case?

Comment: @user225626 - I don't know anything about how PHP .NET interop works, so are you sure it's compatible with .net 4?

Comment: I just did a gacutil.exe /l | clip to text and searched for my ClassLibrary1 and there's nothing.  Yet ClassLibrary1 appears in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\

Comment: It's reputed to be compatible with .net 4.  But now I'm wondering if I even have an assembly to work with [comment immediately above].